# assigning to 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *' ) from incompatible type 'void *'

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
 uint8_t *bufferPtr=NULL;
 size_t bufferPtrSize=0;
 bufferPtr=malloc(bufferPtrSize *  sizeof(uint8_t))
```

I have used this same code in File1.m it is working fine. When I am using this on File2.mm it is giving me `assigning to 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *'  ) from incompatible type 'void *'`error.

Comment: Wow, a new memory function called `mallioc` !! Must be awesome.  Your actual code is correct right?

Comment: @borrrden Yeah the same code I have copied from File1 to File2

Comment: There are tons of spelling and code format errors, I hope you didn't copy those too.

Comment: nope I am sure with that. After you had pointed the mistake, I have cross checked it again.

Comment: I am no expert with these things, but what happens if you cast it to unit8_t?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `.mm` files aren't treated as normal Objective-C files but as Objective-C++ files, so the type rules of C++ apply here. In C++, if you decide to have a type (in this case you have a void pointer) and then want another type (in your case a char pointer), then you have to explicitly cast them. The way to do this is `static_cast<T>()` where `T` is the target type. Ie: `uint8_t *bufferPtr = static_cast<uint8_t *>(malloc(bufferPtrSize *  sizeof(uint8_t)));`